# Facebook messenger iOS apple pay

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, facebook-messenger, messenger, applepay

I am checking if facebook messenger will open up apple pay option. I tried but safari supports apple pay, but not a web browser inside facebook messenger.

Is there a way to go around it today.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the answer is no, since it's specific to Safari.